# How can I match the properties of a specific resin, outside of the manufacturer's specification?

Tags: resin

One may wish to identify resin with identical, or close to physical properties that could be used as a substitute for any specific type of resin, without the need to change other attributes. To use purely as an example, Elegoo Standard Gray Resin.

There exist multiple printers in multiple locations, from different manufacturers, which have each been calibrated to print with Elegoo standard  gray resin.

Printers are often calibrated based on the properties of a specific resin, but also based on the individual characteristics of the printer and the environmental factors of the area in which they are located. For example, slower lift times for those located in an area that has to be kept cooler, and faster for areas that are kept warmer.

The goal is to identify a resin that can be seamlessly exchanged once existing stock of the manufacturer specified resin are depleted, without the need to adjust or recalibrate anything, and without a loss of quality.

A good answer will be based on personal experience and specific use case, and will provide examples of fundamental similarities between products.

A bad answer will be a copy and paste of a data sheet in which a manufacturer states that that a product has similar properties, or anything that states "just google it".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is incredibly close to a recommendation question. You could rewrite it to ask about a specific color, which would identify a color similar to RAL or other standard color number, which would be allowable and not recommendation.

Comment: I'm asking you to remove the vote to close on the grounds that this is an objective question about the properties of a resin. Not a subjective question about "Does it print good".

Comment: @Trish, Is asking for a resin that matches the Gray of Elegoo standard Gray not functionally equivalent of what you just said?

Comment: No. One is "give me a brand" which is banned. One is "what are the specs", which is allowed

Comment: IMHO, This *seems* like a shopping question, unfortunately: `To identify resin that could be used as a substitute for Elegoo standard Gray`

Comment: @Greenonline, soerry, but you have misunderstood. I'm trying to match the mechanical properties, not get a brand recommendation. Please withdraw your vote to close

Comment: @Trish, isn't that exactly what I've just asked.

Comment: @Trish, now that I've clarified that this is not a "recommend me" question, please withdraw your down vote.

Comment: I think the question is fully salvageable if it's rewritten as "Please teach me the procedure of determining parameters of a resin and searching, or creating/modifying another resin to get the same parameters" and the entire "Elegoo Grey" stuff to be scrapped entirely, or (IMO preferably) moved into a separate "Question background"/"Rationale" section, explaining why you need this knowledge, without being an actual part of the question.

Instead of a specific "what to buy" make it clear "how to obtain", asking to be taught the general procedure instead of getting a specific product.

Comment: @SF. - Seems like a good idea.

Comment: I haven't voted either way (yet). Hopefully I won't need to :-) The ideas of SF. seem useful. Unfortunately, IMHO, this bit: `A good answer will be based on personal experience and specific use case` *might* seem to turn it from a shopping-question into an opinion-based question (but I don't know really). Hopefully, you can get the wording just right and a good answer.

Comment: @Greenonline, I'm asking for an answer backed up by experience. If I was looking for manufacturers specifications I could Google them. If someone chooses to give an opinion that's not what I'm asking for, so it would be best to take it up with them individually.